# 'Answered' Python what is wrong with my if statement? (raw_input)

Tags: python, if-statement, urllib

What I want to check for is if the user input is an empty string. I want the code to execute and output: "No input", however whenever I enter no input it goes to the next if statement and executes that with a blank value.

```
import urllib
import re 
myString = " "
i = 0

def getStockPrice():
    text_file = open("data.txt", "w")
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + symbolslist
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()

    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + symbolslist+ '">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)

    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    if str(price) == myString:
        print "No input"
    else:
        print "the price of", symbolslist," is ", price
        text_file.write(str(price))
        text_file.close()




dino = raw_input("What stock would you like to Check?: ")
symbolslist = dino
getStockPrice()

while i < 1000:
    lilly = raw_input("What other stocks do you want to check?: ")
    symbolslist = lilly
    getStockPrice()
```

Comment: Correct this line first `regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + symbolslist+ '">(.+?)</span> ` !!

Comment: you haven't defined `myString` in `if str(price) == myString:`

Comment: Empty string is the one which `len(String) == 0`. In your case `len(MyString)` == `1`

Comment: `myString = " " `  is not empty string!

Comment: `myString` is not **global**.

Comment: myString should be "", not " ". On an unrelated note, you need to pass symbolslist into your function.

Comment: `myString` is global, but it hasn't been declared within the function as `global`, which is okay, because you only need to do that if you want to do more than just access it.

Answer (score 0):

"Empty string is the one which len(String) == 0. In your case len(MyString) == 1"_wanderlust2

This gave me some insight on the issue, it was very amateurish for me to make this mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Python, an empty string evaluates to `False`. That means that you can use a simple code to improve your if statement:

```
user_input = raw_input("Stock to check")
user_input = user_input.strip() # be sure to clear any whitespace!
if user_input:
    # continue on with your program
    ...
```

If you use this Python idiom, your code will be more concise and easier to read. If you get used to it, you'll understand other Python programs that use the feature too.

For your code, I would refactor what you have to something like this:

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input("Stock to check")
    user_input = user_input.strip() # be sure to clear any whitespace!
    if user_input:
        if user_input.lower() == 'quit':
            break
        getStockPrice(user_input)
```

That would rely on you changing your `getStockPrice` function to accept an argument though! That's a simple change. Try adding an extra word within your parentheses:

```
def getStockPrice(symbolslist):
```